# Get unique identifier for ContextMenu in Android?

Tags: android, xml, contextmenu, uniqueidentifier, android-inflate

Have defined xml for my context menu `mymenu.xml`.
Want every menu inflated from this xml to provide same unique identifier - so I know it was inflated from `mymenu.xml` file.

Tried `hashCode()` or `toString()` on `Menu` but found out,
that new `ContextMenu` instance is created on every `onCreateContextMenu` call and so these values differ.

`<menu>` tag cannot have some unique attribute set also.

So, my question:
Is it possible to get `String` containing name of xml from which was menu inflated,
( in my case `"mymenu"`),
 or some other per-xml unique value, which would not be defined programatically by me?
(for example summing `id`'s from all its `MenuItem`s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out, that `R.menu.mymenu` does that. It returns unique `int` per xml.